# How to show microsoft graph calendar in a webpage

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api

how does on show xml from graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar in a webpage?

i've been stuck for 2 weeks trying to get the API call to work and now that it finnaly works i want it so that i'm getting  the XML to show up in my own webpage

[My web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gebJ3.png)

```
------GuzzleHttp api call------


 try {
        $calendar_xml = $client->request('GET', "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar",['headers' => [ "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $access_token->access_token] ]);
    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e){
        dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
    }


$data = $calendar_xml->getBody()->getContents()



------HTML BLADE TEMPLATE------


<iframe srcdoc="{{$calendar_link}}" type="xml" width="100%" height="75%"></iframe>



{{dd(simplexml_load_file($calendar_link))}}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @farooq i added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This broad question can be answered by looking at the [Microsoft Graph PHP Training Module](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-phpapp). It demonstrates how to show calendar information obtained from Microsoft Graph in a Laravel application.

Let us know if that sample is helpful.